# weird issue with output to text in C

Tags: c

This error is driving me nuts. Please help. The code compiles in gcc in terminal and in codeblocks IDE. I'm using Linux and C. It compiles and runs but theres no output in the second text file "onlydata.txt".

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*          Data Looks Like This...
E1 101223 9.2
E1 120231 8.4
E2 121212 400.2
            I need this....
          9.2
          8.4
 */

struct Data
{
 char        *specimen;
 int           date;
 double        result;
};

int main()
{
 char szBuffer[256];
 unsigned int iCt=0;
 Data* pData=NULL;
 FILE* fpIn=NULL;

 fpIn=fopen("data.txt","r");  //Open "Data.dat for read "r" access.
 if(fpIn)                     //and loop through data to count lines.
 {                            //in iCt
    while(!feof(fpIn))
    {
       fgets(szBuffer,256,fpIn);
       iCt++;
    }
    fclose(fpIn);
 }
 printf("iCt = %d\n\n",iCt);             //Allocate a buffer of Data type
 pData=(Data*)malloc(iCt*sizeof(Data));  //to hold iCt objects
 if(pData)
 {
    fpIn=fopen("Data.txt","r");  //Open "Data.dat for read "r" access.
    if(fpIn)          FILE *fp=NULL;

    {
       iCt=0;
       while(!feof(fpIn))      //read data from text file into buffer
       {
          fscanf(fpIn,"%s%i%f",
          &pData[iCt].specimen,
          &pData[iCt].date,
          &pData[iCt].result);

         // printf("%10.2f\t%4.2f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%u\t%4.2f\n",
         // pData[iCt].specimen,
         // pData[iCt].date,
         // pData[iCt].result,

          iCt++;
          FILE *np=NULL;
        np = fopen("onlydata.txt","w");
        if(np)
         fprintf (np," ", &pData[iCt].result);
         fclose(np);
       }
       fclose(fpIn);
    }
    free(pData);
 }
 getchar();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `np` is not `NULL`?

Comment: "if(fpIn)          FILE *fp=NULL;" probably needs some braces. Aso you usage of feof() is wrong.

Comment: you need to have specifier in your fprintf for the result, without the specifier it just writes a whitespace into the file..

Comment: You do not allocate memory for `pData[iCt].specimen`, and you should not pass it to `fscanf` with `&`: That is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Als, you must check the return value from `fscanf`.

Comment: You read "specimen" into random memory locations: You never allocated memory for those strings. (The Data structure has a pointer to char which remains unallocated.) And the other comments above are valid too. Why code this in C anyway ? The "cut" command does exactly this.

Comment: you all get thumbs up! thank you didler , joachin, tonny <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem you have stems from the following line:

```
fprintf (np," ", &pData[iCt].result);
```

It simply outputs a space to the file. I think you forgot a `%f`.

**EDIT** Missed the other obvious error noted by Didier Trosset. :)

Answer (score 3):

Linux filenames are case sensitive. The second fopen() will fail if the file is called "data.txt".

Answer (score 1):

You should open you destination file only once, at the same time you open your source file.

Right now, for every line of the source file, you open the destination, truncate it, and write one line. In the end, you only got a single line (the last one) in your destination file.

Furthermore, your `fprintf` does only write a single space character: your format string should be `"%f"` or at least contain one `%f`. Actually, the parameter `&pData[iCt].result` is not used.

Note also that this parameter should not be passed by address, but by value: (remove the `&`).

Comment: Check the ques again, he says the output file is empty.

Comment: Yes. Because the destination file is overwritten again and again, with only one line each time. Furthermore, the last line does not match the `fscanf` (`*/`).

Answer (score 1):

you need to have specifier in your fprintf for the result, without the specifier it just writes a whitespace into the file